# Div with background matches text height

Tags: css

Note: IE 8+ is a must :-(

What I currently have,

[image]

This is what I want,

[image]

It is about the part

```
<div style="background-color: red;height: 20px;width: 10px; ...
```

This is what I am trying - https://jsfiddle.net/w3tjbvef/3/

```html
<table id="sometable" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="s-row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Name With Colour Yellow 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t-row">
      <td>Tag</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <div style="background-color: red;height: 20px;width: 10px;/* margin-top: 10px; */display: inline-block;"></div>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="time-row">
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>111111111</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owner-row">
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>asdasd</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="desc-row">
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>Bag With Colour Yellow 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<table id="sometable" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="s-row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Name With Colour Yellow 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t-row">
      <td>Tag</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>

          <div style="border-left: 10px solid red;padding-left: 10px;">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="time-row">
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>111111111</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owner-row">
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>asdasd</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="desc-row">
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>Bag With Colour Yellow 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<td>

          <div style="border-left: 10px solid red; padding-left: 10px;">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live.</div>
      </td>
```

I'd create a class and add it instead of inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using `display: flex` on parent div of the element with red line. That will make all the child elements equal in height.

```html
<table id="sometable" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="s-row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Name With Colour Yellow 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t-row">
      <td>Tag</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div style="display: flex">
          <div style="background-color: red; width: 10px; margin-right: 10px"></div>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="time-row">
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>111111111</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owner-row">
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>asdasd</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="desc-row">
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>Bag With Colour Yellow 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You could also use CSS table layout.

```html
<table id="sometable" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="s-row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Name With Colour Yellow 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t-row">
      <td>Tag</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div style="display: table">
          <div style="background-color: red; width: 10px; margin-right: 10px; display: table-cell"></div>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="time-row">
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>111111111</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owner-row">
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>asdasd</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="desc-row">
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>Bag With Colour Yellow 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add ie8+ is a must :(

Answer (score 0):

target the td element instead of the inner div, and give it an inline style like this;

```
<td style="border-left : 10px solid red; padding-left : 8px;">
```

Or you could use the same inline style on the inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Try with border-left

```html
<table id="sometable" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="s-row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Name With Colour Yellow 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t-row">
      <td>Tag</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div style="border-left: 10px solid red; padding-left: 5px;">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">  </div>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="time-row">
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>111111111</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owner-row">
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>asdasd</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="desc-row">
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>Bag With Colour Yellow 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table id="sometable" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="s-row">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>Name With Colour Yellow 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t-row">
      <td>Tag</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div style="vertical-align: middle;position:relative;">
          <div style="background-color: red;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;width: 10px;"></div>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live.
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="time-row">
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>111111111</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owner-row">
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>asdasd</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="desc-row">
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <div>Bag With Colour Yellow 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done easily with CSS Grid Layout.
To do that you are gonna need to create 3 columns and two rows, with the width that matches your expectations.
":" would be indside the second column.

Comment: The question specified IE 8+, but IE didn't start supporting grid layout until version 10, and at that point it wasn't complete support.